# When to place definite article 'the' before a pronoun ('you', 'he', etc...)

Tags: definite-article, pronouns

First: I've read [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26772/should-we-use-article-the-before-pronouns-he-she-them-it-etc) answer, however it was not quite useful for me. [1]

In an animation I heard a character saying "the you", but how it is correct (The animation was voiced by Americans.)? I checked both the subtitle and my ears, the character really said "The you"!

The Dialoge (S2E3 "The Ballad of Duke Baloney")

> Webby: Fishing,... The noble struggle of man versus nature

> Louie: The you gently rowing me around for several hours while I nap

So the question: Why did that character say this? is it correct? and when to use this [sentence structure (Definite article + pronoun)]?

---

1. Unlike that question, I saw 'the' before 'you' in an American animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is conversational sarcasm. Everything after 'the' could be placed in quotation marks, and is a sarcastic interpretation of the first speaker's grand sounding words.

> Webby: Fishing,... The noble struggle of man versus nature
> Louie: The "you gently rowing me around for several hours while I nap".

> Me: The profound contemplation of life and death in our time.
> My wife: The "you watching a thriller movie on TV".

> The Prime Minister: The great mission of of this government
> Me: The "you and your supporters getting rich while I starve"